# Can I see how a company is using its debt?

Tags: debt, income, balance-sheet, leverage

How can I understand the way that way a company is using its borrowed funds?

From the balance sheet I can see how much debt the company issued, and how much is paid back. But how can I see if the debt is a “good” or “bad” debt? Can I see how the company is spending its debt, and the return it is earning from using it?

Answer (score 34):

Money is 'fungible'. That means that any single dollar in circulation is identical to every other. If I pick up a lucky quarter on the street, and put it into my right pocket, then when I buy a candy at the store it is irrelevant whether I pay with that quarter or from a quarter I had in my left pocket. Whether you consider it a 'right pocket' quarter or a 'left pocket' quarter, I still have the same amount of money in total.

So asking 'what a company does with its debt' is basically the same as asking 'what money did the company spend in the year?'

Look at the published cashflow statement to see this - it will show incoming debt funds, debt repayments, operating cashflows, and investments in the business.

In some cases, for significant enough cash movements, the financial statements might disclose something like "such and such project required $x investment, which was partially funded through $y in additional debt".

I will caution you that this is a fairly basic concept, so if you are preparing to do some analysis of a company's financial statements for investment purposes, I suggest you keep studying before putting your own money at risk.

The question regarding determining if the debt is 'good' or 'bad' is more difficult to answer - one thing to watch for would be the income compared with annual interest costs, and also any notes which describe when the debt becomes due. This will form one part of analysis of the company's finances, and is a much broader question.

Comment: make sense to check the income/Total debt ratio? to see if the company generate a good return on it? and which is a good ratio? example Apple- Total debt:136B, Income:94.6B ->Return=69% so for each € of debt he generated 0.69cent. If we see Walt Disney they have huge debt compared to Operating cash so Total debt:58, Income:1.9- Return=3.3%, so what return value limit is good?

Comment: @DevLeo Different companies and different industries will impact the necessity / risk / value of debt. "How much debt is good?" is far too complex to answer here, and if you think simple answers will provide you an 'edge' in investing, then I again caution you that you may be in over your head.

Comment: You're right that there is no way to define "how a company is using its debt" (versus other available funds) based on the *bare factual accounting data*. However, as a matter of *strategy and intent*, it is meaningful to ask, "What did the company spend money on that it *would not have done* if it had not borrowed these funds?" This counterfactual is not straightforward to answer, and may be totally inscrutable from outside, but at some level there is an executive who knows the answer. If known, this could be used to evaluate whether the company showed good judgment in deciding to borrow.

Comment: The law, which can deal with evidence of *intent* and not just bare accounting data, does indeed [prescribe](https://www.google.com/search?q=loan+"funds+must+be+used+for") in various cases how borrowed funds can be "used".

Comment: And certain things can suddenly make things very bad for a company. Look at real estate developers in China. They used to be able to use debt as collateral to get more credit, but that has suddenly stopped and no developer in China is able to acquire more credit, which means it is actually a massive problem in the entire sector.

Comment: @nanoman If company A has a failing division with excess costs absorbed by net income, decides to take on debt to fund a new branch, that is functionally identical to company B funding its new branch from net income and taking on debt to continue operation of its own failing division. You could argue that company B is more foolhardy to take on debt for a failing division, and I would counter that company A doesn't even have the information gathering to understand that without its failing division, it wouldn't need to take on new debt for the new division.

Comment: The point is that from the outside, the two situations are identical, and even on the inside, they are only different to the extent that *future management decisions* will be different based on that mindset. ie: I accept that a company purposefully funding a failing division with debt is likely to continue to sink to bankruptcy, but for that to be functionally different than the other scenario, you would need to show me that the other company is about to actually make a different decision, at which point the two companies diverge and are different again. Management intent is imho inscrutable.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: Assuming that the company is publicly-traded (which is a reasonable assumption because investors in privately-traded companies should be in a position to ask directly), it should be filing some sort of annual disclosure, which will necessarily include a risk assessment, which in turn should give a broad overview of the kinds of things that management is (currently) concerned about and the risks they (believe they) are taking. This is obviously not perfect, but it is significantly better than nothing.

Comment: @Kevin Yes - but there is no point in pretending that this $ for x project came from y funding source vs this other $ for z project came from a different funding source. Money is fungible.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Money isn't always fungible. For instance, if the government issues a bond to build a bridge, the funds may be deposited into an account that can only be used for the bridge project, rather than going into a general pool of unrestricted funds.

Comment: @Barmar That is precisely the exception that proves the rule - the only way to turn fungible money into non-fungible asset is to legally separate it from the remainder. Because money is fungible.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon It's not just legal. Businesses create budgets for different uses, and these are often tied to income sources. If you go to a bank for a loan, they want to know what your intended use is before they'll approve it. I understand that companies (and even goverments) often treat these as fuzzy barriers, but the intent is there.

Comment: @barmar Again - management 'intent', to the extent it is discernable to an outsider, and *also* to the extent that it actually has an impact on the course of a business, could impact that company's profitability. But to look back historically and say "this quarter was used to make a phone call, and those 2 dimes and a nickel were used to buy candy" is irrelevant. Why am I being persistent on this point? Because improperly implying causality in a set of financial statements, by attributing financial success to new loans and ignoring financial loss elsewhere, is just putting lipstick on a pig.

Comment: As I think someone mentioned, if it's a public company, they may include details like this in their annual report.

Comment: @barmar Yes. I mentioned that.